# Rails assign id in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to assign the event_option_id to the registration. I can easily do it in the view by adding this to the form:

```
<%= f.text_field :event_option_id, value: @event_option.id  %>
```

I would like to do it in the model not in the view. For security I'm doing the same for the registration price. Setting the price from the model is working but doing the same thing for the event_option_id is not.

**Registration Model:**

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event_option
  belongs_to :order_item
  belongs_to :order

  before_save :set_event_options



  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def registration_price
    self[:price] = event_option.price
  end
  def event_option_id
    self.event_option_id = event_option
  end

private

def set_event_options
    self[:price] = registration_price
  self.event_option_id = event_option_id

end

end
```

**EventOptions model:**

```
class EventOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :registrations
end
```

**Create Method in the Registrations controller:**

```
  def create
    @event_option = EventOption.find(params[:id]) 
    @order = current_order
    @registration = @order.registrations.build(registration_params)
    #@registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
    @order_id = current_order.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration.save
        format.html { redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @registration }
        format.js {}
        @order.save
        session[:order_id] = @order.id
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

**Error in log:**

```
Started POST "/registrations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-04 21:16:06 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âo"", "registration"=>{"name"=>"saasas", "lastname"=>"asas"}, "commit"=>"Create Registration"}
  EventOption Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "event_options".* FROM "event_options" WHERE "event_options"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find EventOption with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:27:in `create'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (44.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (48.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (105.0ms)
```

I'm reading this part of the rails documentation: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html, 
but still can't figure out whats going on.

**Update:**

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :cart, only: [:show]
  resources :orders
  resources :order_items
  resources :registrations
  resources :event_options
  resources :events
  resources :charges

  root 'events#index'
```

**Registration form - inside event_option show.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@registration, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @registration.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@registration.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this registration from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @registration.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post more of your logs?  And what route are you hitting?  Is registration a child of event_option?  Post routes, more of your logs (include params), and it would be great to see the form in the view.

Comment: I've updated the post with the log and routes.Registration is a child of event_option but I'm not nesting routes.

Comment: Nest the route so you get the `event_option_id` that way, if you don't want to send it through the view.

Comment: Do you know why I can set the price of the registration passing the price of the event_option but can't do the same for the id?

Comment: Are you sending the price in the params?  It's not in the logs

Comment: I'm not sending the price in  params. All I'm doing is setting it in the model before_save. Is not in the logs because it stopped working when I added the set_event_option_id method in the registration model. But if I removed the set_event_option_id method from the model, the price works fine.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `self.event_option_id = event_option.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your controller's `create` function is missing `params[:id]`.

The easiest way to fix is adding it into your form:

```
<%= form_for(@registration, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, your_event_option_id %>
  ### your other stuffs
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing that I had working well before. The thing about this is that a user can use dev tools to change the id of the event option. What I'm trying to do is to set the event option id in the model. That way I don't have to include either a text or a hidden field in the form. I'm currently passing the price of the registration from the event option straight from the model. This is working fine. That's why I don't understand why is it not working with the id. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that Rails is unable to find an `EventOption` without an `id`:

```
def create
   @event_option = EventOption.find params[:id] #-> :id is not passed to create action
```

To fix it, just use the `param` that's submitted as part of the form:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @order        = current_order
      @registration = @order.registrations.new registration_params
      @registration.save
   end

   private

   def registration_params
      params.require(:registration).permit(:event_option_id, :other, :params)
   end
end
```

--

The above would work well if the user could choose the `event_option_id` in the form; if you're using a `hidden_field`, you'll be better using `nested routes`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :event_option do
   resources :registrations #-> url.com/event_options/:event_option_id/registrations/new
end
```

This will set the `event_option_id` as part of the top-level params hash, which will be passed to the controller as `params[:event_option_id]` (as you have it already):

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @event_option = EventOption.find params[:event_option_id]
   end
end
```

---

Tip - you can [declare multiple resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time) at once:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :cart, only: [:show]
resources :orders, :order_items, :registrations, :event_options, :events, :charges
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.